# how can I inject different text into "included" layout items?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have this xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:padding="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="#B24700"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.30" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="--"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="0.60" />



</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

which i include in here:

[image]

how can i inject the "new text" to be different in each item.

Comment: it's possible only programmatically

Comment: @Elad Benda : include is used for common layouts. Not for different..!!

Comment: include is used only for layouts normally

Comment: @MamataGelanee so what will you use if the difference is only one text?

Comment: @JatinKumar so what will you use if the difference is only one text?

Comment: @ Elad Benda : you want different background or font style like UI differance then do it programmetically..

Answer (score 0):

As I know, this cannnot be done with `<include/>` itself, the closest thing is to create your own widget class, in the class you inflate from the xml and read a custom attributes and set the value, e.g. text in TextView programmatically.